# Friendly_Id and Reserved Words -- How can i replace the reserved word?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, friendly-id

Here is an example of what causes the error:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :004 > Post.new(title: "new").save!
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE (`slug` = 'new' OR `slug` LIKE 'new--%') ORDER BY LENGTH(`slug`) DESC, `slug` DESC LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`lsi_post_id` = BINARY '' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Friendly is reserved
```

I would like to put something in the Post model that maybe replaces a new word with "-" or something along those lines but I'm not sure where to start.

Thank you!

Comment: I'd like to add that using words that will be turned into a slug such as "Admin" in my case is what caused this. When I was seeding my db I made my username something other than Admin so that the slug would not conflict with reserved words. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the answers by **daemonsy** and **SizzlePants** I came up with this, which quietly renames "new" to "new2" and "edit" to "edit2", and keeps everything else as before:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :friendly_id_title, use: :slugged
  def friendly_id_title
    case title.parameterize
    when 'new' then 'new2'
    when 'edit' then 'edit2'
    else title
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed this is an old question. Would very much like to know how you solved the problem too.

The 7 RESTFul keywords are blocked by Friendly as slug choices. The offender here is `new`.

From your code, it seems that you are trying to set the slug to "new" as it is the title of your post.

In order to prevent the reserved words from being used, you can make the slug generator use a method instead of a column.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId 

  friendly_id :name_and_id, :use=>:slugged # Used slugged mode, need a slug column in db.

  def name_and_id
    "#{id}-#{name}"
  end

end
```

From this sample code, when creating a post with the name `my post`,  going to `localhost:3000/posts/1-my-post` works. The `-` separator is added automatically and can be changed.

See [Friendly Id Guide.rdoc](http://rubydoc.info/github/norman/friendly_id/master/file/Guide.rdoc) for more details.

Comment: I posted my solution... Your solution is much more simple.

Comment: They both work=). But perhaps if you have a reserved_words, you have to maintain them, each new ver of FriendlyID might add/remove words. Appending Id to name will make the slug always unique (fingers crossed). The reserved words in friendly is good for making sure you don't end up using action words. Thanks for the post!

Comment: this may need a little more thought, friendly_id uses `before` validation, so ID is not available at the time the slug is generated. If you want to do this, you can either do a 'double-save' via an observer to update the ID or simply avoid using the ID in the custom slug method.

Comment: When I used Friendly ID, the appending of id-name worked on a new record. Hopefully FriendlyID is not "guessing" what the new ID is. I'll investigate again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how i got around things.. I'm really not sure if it's right or wrong... but i'm using it for now.  Would really love to hear other suggestions.

My application helper looks something like this:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  # Friendly_Id reserved words
  def niceify_slug(s)
    clean_slug = s
    reserved_words = ["new", "edit"]
    reserved_words.each { |word| clean_slug = clean_slug.gsub(/\b#{word}\b/i, "#{word}_") }

    return clean_slug
  end
end
```

My model looks something like this:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ApplicationHelper

  # Slugs via FriendlyId
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :niceified_name, :use => :slugged

  def niceified_name
    niceify_slug(self.name)
  end
end
```